# inserting key value pair in associate multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, insert

I have a multi dimensional array named $p_result which contains product related data now I want to add another key value element (with key "o_id" and value 4) into it using for each or for loop but so far I have tried this

```
foreach($p_result as $prod){
    $prod['o_id']=4;
}
print_r($p_result);
```

but its not adding [oid]=>4 into each of the array.print_r($p_result) shows

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [p_id] => 7 [quantity] => 122 [unitPrice] => 3 [subTotal] => 366 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [p_id] => 8 [quantity] => 133 [unitPrice] => 5 [subTotal] => 665 ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as &$prod:

```
foreach($p_result as &$prod){
    $prod['o_id']=4;
}
print_r($p_result);
```

Comment: its awesome will you please elaborate the use of & over here?

Comment: It is described here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
"In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."

Comment: And there are very helpful note:
"Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset()."

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want by using the [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) operator `&`:

```
foreach($p_result as &$prod) {
    $prod['o_id']=4;
}
```

The reference operator allows you to access the parent variable because you are actually referring to the original variable.

Occasionally using reference can be problematic, in which case another option is:

```
foreach($p_result as $index => $prod) {
    $p_result[$index]['o_id']=4;
}
```

Comment: @FaisalNaseer - it works, I'd need to see the code you are using / trying to help troubleshoot it further.